# No such file or directory

Tags: python, filepath

I try to concatenate the string to a directory to open the image with the code:

```
for i in wrong_lable:
  for label in ('cat','dog'):
    path = '/content/transfer/Train/'
    image = f'{label}.{i}.jgp' 
    x =  os.path.join(path,label,image)
    #im = Image.open(x)
    print(x)
```

The output:

```
/content/transfer/Train/cat/cat.2981.jgp
/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.2981.jgp
/content/transfer/Train/cat/cat.3845.jgp
/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.3845.jgp
/content/transfer/Train/cat/cat.3714.jgp
/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.3714.jgp
```

But when I try to open it it has a problem:

```
im = Image.open('/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.2981.jpg') #from my drive
im = Image.open('/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.2981.jgp') #from my code ouput
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-254-89eb73c74b08> in <module>()
      1 im = Image.open('/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.2981.jpg')
----> 2 im = Image.open('/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.2981.jgp')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2841 
   2842     if filename:
-> 2843         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2844         exclusive_fp = True
   2845 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/transfer/Train/dog/dog.2981.jgp'
```

In the first row the path I copy in the collab folder. In The second row the path I copy in my code output.

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Unless you're doing something weird I suspect that you should change jgp to jpg.

Answer (score 0):

in image variable you have given extension 'jgp' while correct extension is 'jpg'.
change it first and then try again.

Comment: Ok, I'm just new here so I don't know much here

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness.